# Hilbert's original proof of basis theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, math-history

Does anyone know Hilbert's original proof of his basis theorem--the non-constructive version that caused all the controversy?  I know this was circa 1890, and he would have proved it for $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Since this was before Emmy Noether's "Ideal theory for Rings", he would not have had the ascending chain condition to prove it.  I wanted to know how his original proof compares with Emmy's a decade or so later, and in particular how his proof hints at the formulation of the ascending chain condition.

Comment: You can find Hilbert's "Gesammelte Abhandlungen" (collected publications) in digitized form at the University of Goettingen: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/toc/?PPN=PPN237820250  The documents are in German.

Comment: A related survey with lots of references: http://smf4.emath.fr/en/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/3/pdf/smf_rhm_3_1-48.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at those! :D

Comment: For what it's worth, Noether's proof "a decade or so later" was about 30 years later (1921).

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a hold of:  "Theory Of Algebraic Invariants" by David Hilbert (pp.126-130) , Lecture XXXV ( July 9, 1897) the original proof is given. This book is an English translation published by Cambridge University Press.